# Is given non constant continuous map is correct or not?

Tags: general-topology

Is the following statement true or false?

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a nonconstant continuous map of topological spaces. 
If $X$ is Hausdorff then $f(X)$ is Hausdorff.

My attempt:  I was reading this answer  but  i did not understands anything [image]

can anybody explain this statement: If $X$ is Hausdorff then $f(X)$ is Hausdorff...... in detail and please tell me the solution..i would be more thankful.

Comment: this is not true in general.. the author (Alireza) assumes that $Y$ is a $T_B$ space... and that $X$ is compact.

Comment: @James : That's not necessarily true in general. The statement true if $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorhism.

Answer (score 0):

A topological space $(X, \tau_X)$ is Hausdorff whenever every pair of distinct points have disjoint neighbourhoods. Note that this is really a condition on the topology $\tau_X$.

Take $f: X \to Y$. Define

$$ f(X) = \{ f(x) : x \in X \} \subseteq Y. $$

Whenever $f(X) = Y$ (that is, $f$ is *onto*), then it is clear what the topology on $f(X)$ is. But if $f(X)$ is a proper subset of $Y$, then we normally take the topology on $f(X)$ to be the relative topology

$$ \tau_f = \{ U \cap f(X) : U \in \tau_Y \}. $$

The claim (which, as noted in the comments, is not true in general) that $f(X)$ is Hausdorff whenever $X$ is Hausdorff should now be fairly self-explanatory.

To see why it is not true (even for continuous $f$), let $\tau_Y$ be the trivial topology consisting of only $Y$ and the empty set. $f$ is (trivially) continuous. Observe now that, as long as $Y$ is non-empty and not a singleton (and $f$ is not constant), $f(X)$ is not Hausdorff, even if $X$ is.

Note that $Y$ is not $T_B$ (as long as $Y$ is non-empty and not a singleton).

Comment: @ Theoretical Economist,,,,,im not getting,.line,......let τY be the trivial topology consisting of only Y and the empty set. f is (trivially) continuous.,,,,,can u elaborate  more ?

Comment: The trivial topology is defined as I described it. Any function whose codomain has the trivial topology is continuous. Proving this is an easy exercise, so I will leave that to you.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma you’re right; I had forgotten about this. I will fix my answer.